# jQuery/Prestashop - Can't get value from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm strugling to get a value from an text input field inside a form.
I'm trying to get the value of a field in the product page in PrestaShop, that field is created through a module and a client can insert text to ask for engraving.

The code I have works outside prestashop, like you can test below.

I've searched and tried a million things and cannot make it work, maybe because it's in Prestashop.

```js
var textopresente = null;

$(document).on("click", "#symbol-heart", function () {

  console.log("click");

  textopresente = $('#formula').val();

  if ($("#formula")) {
    console.log(textopresente + "yes");
  };

  //testing purposes
  $("#formula").val(textopresente + 'Teste');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text form-control an_pf_text" id="formula" name="{$input_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">

<div class="input-symbols">
  <span id="symbol-heart" class="symbol-btn">❤</span>
</div>
```

The HTML is inside the module tpl file for the hook in question.
The JS is the JS file that's imported in the module aswell. I tried putting the js in the tpl file and in the global JS theme file but it never works.

I leave you the link to my sandbox store page: https://sandbox.anjo.com.pt/contas-mulher/conta-mulher-pandora-narval-798965c01

Hope someone can help me :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about additional field? https://prnt.sc/fv_nNBXhRcMl

Comment: @Sachin yes, that field. I was making a few more tests changing it to a textarea instead of an input but that's the field.

Comment: okay, when do you want to save that field value on add to cart button?

Comment: @Sachin yes, but that is working already, I have a module that adds this field, I'm just trying to extend it do add unicode symbols by clicking on buttons (span's), but the value of the input is always undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code and let me know if it works for you.

```
$(document).on("click", "#symbol-heart", function () {

            console.log("click");

            var textopresente = $('.an_pf_text').val();;

            if ($(".an_pf_text")) {
                console.log(textopresente + "yes");
            };

            $(".an_pf_text").val(textopresente + 'Teste');
            
           
        });
```

Comment: This works! But why does the selection by Id doesn't work? I tried million things but not changing the selector...